# Powershell run a setup executable from repository

Tags: powershell, github

I am trying to create a script which executes a setup executable from a git hub repository, is that possible without downloading the file?

Link to the repository: https://github.com/rarehalf/Smartmontools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use Invoke-WebRequest with -OutFile parameter.

```
Invoke-WebRequest
```

it will download the file from GitHub and put it into what ever directory you are currently in, so for you it would be

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/rarehalf/Smartmontools/raw/main/smartmontools-7.2-1.win32-setup.exe -OutFile "smartmontools-7.2-1.win32-setup.exe"
```

you can then call this in your script and run using the below

```
.\smartmontools-7.2-1.win32-setup.exe
```

Comment: Can this be done without downloading the file?

Comment: no, in order to run a exe you need to download it